# How can I prevent a form-control from taking a new line in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the dropdown menu to appear next to text "Pay every". How can I do this with bootstrap classes without editing the css or giving it a new custom class?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Offer:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="$1000"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="i-checks col-sm-1">
            <label class="control-label"> <input type="radio" value="option1" name="a" checked> All at once </label>
        </div>

        <div class="i-checks col-sm-2">
            <label class="control-label"> <input type="radio" value="option1" name="a"> Pay every </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="every" disabled >
                <option>2 weeks</option>
                <option>1 months</option>
                <option>2 months</option>
                <option>3 months</option>
                <option>6 months</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused by your title...do you want the form controls to be inline like in your picture?  Or do you want each control on a new line?

Comment: You can use the form inline: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline | Or you can create a row and place each control in a different col

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put it in a new col?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Offer:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="$1000">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
    <div class="i-checks">
        <label class="control-label"> 
        <input type="radio" value="option1" name="a" checked> All at once </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
    <div class="i-checks">
        <label class="control-label"> <input type="radio" value="option1" name="a"> Pay every </label>
        <select class="form-control" name="every" disabled >
            <option>2 weeks</option>
            <option>1 months</option>
            <option>2 months</option>
            <option>3 months</option>
            <option>6 months</option>
        </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is wrong. Form inline is the right approach, or a row with several cols. Nesting form-groups is not in the docs and it's unnecessary since you already have classes to get the desired behavior.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, I just copy/pasted his code and did the edit.

Comment: Lol you don't need to apologise. Upvote the answer from @IsThatQueeblo, it's right.

Answer (score 23):

The `form-inline` class is the bootstrap class for creating forms with inline controls.  Everything within each `form-group` is displayed inline.

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Offer:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="$1000">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="i-checks">
            <label class="control-label"> 
            <input type="radio" value="option1" name="a" checked> All at once </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="i-checks">
            <label class="control-label"> <input type="radio" value="option1" name="a"> Pay every </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="every" disabled >
                <option>2 weeks</option>
                <option>1 months</option>
                <option>2 months</option>
                <option>3 months</option>
                <option>6 months</option>
            </select>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see how it looks live here: http://www.bootply.com/WXOIcKQN6y